# Ruby Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: Timed out waiting for Selenium session reset Failure/Error

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am continually getting flakey errors on CI where my Selenium session is not restarting. I'm not having this issue when I run tests locally. It only ever happens on my CI server.

I'm using Capybara 2.18.0, rspec 3.7.0, slenium-webdriver 3.9.0 and site_prism 2.13. Is there

```
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: Timed out waiting for Selenium session reset
Failure/Error: raise Capybara::ExpectationNotMet.new('Timed out waiting for Selenium session reset') if (Capybara::Helpers.monotonic_time - start_time) >= 10

Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
  Timed out waiting for Selenium session reset
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:145:in `reset!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:127:in `reset!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara.rb:314:in `block in reset_sessions!'
```

my `spec_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'site_prism'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.save_path = "#{Dir.pwd}/screenshots"

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.app_host = ENV['url']

if ENV['timeout']
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = ENV['timeout'].to_i
else
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.full_backtrace = true

  config.before(:each) do
    config.include Capybara::DSL
  end

  config.after(:each) do |example|
    if example.exception
      name = example.example_group.to_s
      name.slice!('RSpec::ExampleGroups::')
      name.gsub!('::', '#')
      whole_page.save_screenshot("#{name}##{example.description.tr(' ', '_')}-#{Time.now.strftime('%H_%M_%S')}.png")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have the `timeout` environment variable set when running on CI? If so, to what value?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole it is set at 60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Capybara resets the driver, it tells the browser to go to `about:blank` and then waits up to 10 seconds for there to be no elements on the page matching CSS '/html/body/*'.  In your case that isn't happening within 10 seconds.

One reason for this could be you having `onunload` handlers that are doing something that could take longer than 10 seconds on your CI hardware (or opening alert messages, etc)??  If that's the case a workaround is to have the test visit a page that doesn't have an `onunload` handler and check for something visible on that page at the end of the test (potentially in an after block to keep the test clean). Another thing to verify is that the versions of Chrome and chromedriver are the same between local and CI.

Comment: the issue is definitely not alert messages. Hm... Any way to exntend the wait time to more than 10 seconds?

Comment: @Zack fork capybara and modify, if that fixes it then you'd need to look at what your page is doing in onunload and why it's taking so long.  If you do fork and modify you could also add saving of a screenshot in there to see what the page actually looks like when it goes over 10 seconds.